# Critical point of $f(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x-3)^2$

Tags: calculus

> Determine the critical point of $$f(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x-3)^2$$

Firstly, I get the derivative of $f(x)$. I got $=4x(x^2-1)(x-3)^2+2(x-3)(x^2-1)^2$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The function is a polynomial, hence the only points for which the function has a critical point at are the ones whose derivative is zero

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As

$$f(x)=((x^2-1)(x-3))^2=(g(x))^2,$$ the critical points of $f$ will be

- the roots of $g$, $x=\pm1$ and $x=3$;
- the critical points of $g$, which are the zeroes of $g'(x)=2x(x-3)+x^2-1=3x^2-6x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Now, note that\begin{align}4x(x^2-1)(x-3)^2+2(x-3)(x^2-1)^2&=2(x^2-1)(x-3)\bigl(2x(x-3)+x^2-1\bigr)\\&=2(x^2-1)(x-3)(3x^2-6x-1).\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: how did you factorize it can you give me the steps please

Comment: I used the fact that $4x(x^2-1)(x-3)^2=2(x^2-1)(x-3)\times2x(x-3)$ and that $2(x-3)(x^2-1)^2=2(x^2-1)(x-3)\times(x^2-1)$.

Comment: ok thank you after that how many critical point we will get 4 or 5?

Comment: It will have $5$.

Comment: I am asking you alot sorry but how we will get 5 can you help me please

Comment: Because $x^2-1=0$ has $2$ roots ($\pm1$), $x-3=0$ has one root ($1$), and $3x^2-6x-1=0$ has $2$ roots ($1\pm\frac2{\sqrt3}$).

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to use critical points calculator, here is solution at
[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=critical%20points%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22CriticalPointsCalculator%22%2C%20%22curvefunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28%28x%5E2-1%29%5E2%29*%28x-3%29%5E2%22) service.